# Intel AX200 adapter not found on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi

The settings page said that no wifi adapter was found. Here's some relevant information

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:70:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ed100000-ed103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 10
       serial: b0:5c:da:2e:73:f8
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt
```

`sudo dmesg | grep iwl` doesn't output anything, but after running

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/izDjPMVP.

```
[46557.495281] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0: pci_enable_msi failed - -22
[46557.834513] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0: CSR_RESET = 0x10
[46557.834516] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
[46557.834637] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x3f7f0830
[46557.834688] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x3f7f0c30
[46557.834739] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x3f7f8830
[46557.834790] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x3f7f0030
[46557.834841] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x3f7f8430
[46557.834892] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x3f7f0830
[46557.834943] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x3f7f8830
[46557.834994] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x3f7f0c30
[46557.835046] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x3f7f8030
[46557.835097] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x3f7f0030
[46557.835148] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x3f7f8c30
[46557.835199] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x3f7f0c30
[46557.835250] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x3f7f8830
[46557.835301] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x3f7f0430
[46557.835352] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x3f7f8430
[46557.835353] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
[46557.835404] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x044466c2
[46557.835454] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x044466c2
[46557.835506] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x044466c2
[46557.835557] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x044466c2
[46557.835608] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x044466c2
[46557.835733] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x044466c2
[46557.835858] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x044466c2
[46557.835983] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x044466c2
[46557.836035] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x044466c2
[46557.836164] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x044466c2
[46557.836319] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x044466c2
[46557.836459] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x044466c2
[46557.836598] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x044466c2
[46557.836747] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x044466c2
[46557.836891] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x044466c2
[46557.836892] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
[46557.837035] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0xb00c4c71
[46557.837179] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0xf00c4c71
[46557.837307] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0xf00c4c71
[46557.837431] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0xb00c4c71
[46557.837555] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0xf00c4c71
[46557.837609] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0xf00c4c71
[46557.837746] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0xb00c4c71
[46557.837871] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0xa00c4c71
[46557.837998] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0xa00c4c71
[46557.838124] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0xa00c4c71
[46557.838250] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0xa00c4c71
[46557.838376] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0xb00c4c71
[46557.838501] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0xf00c4c71
[46557.838626] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0xb00c4c71
[46557.838751] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0xb00c4c71
[46557.838752] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
[46557.838802] iwlwifi 0000:70:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x00000000
[46557.839079] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:70:00.0 failed with error -110
```

After about 2-3 days of googling, I didn't manage to fix the issue.

My kernel version is: 5.16.0-051600-generic.

Comment: Do you have a dual-boot or only linux?

Comment: Did you try with an Ubuntu kernel instead of a mainline?

Comment: I don't use dual boot. About the kernel, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so apparently what helped me was the computer to drain it's battery.
After turning it on again, the wifi worked!
I don't know what caused the issue, but thus is what worked for me.